# foreach value with key outside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a few foreaches which show a total of some numbers.

One of them is this one:

```
foreach ($lijst['palen'] as $key => $valuepalen) 
{
    echo $valuepalen ."x Bekaclip palen (48mm / lengte " . $??? . " cm" . "\n"; 
}
```

And then there is this one which contains the values I need:

```
foreach ($optellen as $key => $hoogtevalue) 
{

}
```

The values I need is `$hoogtevalue` which contains 100 and 110.
But if I insert `$hoogtevalue` in `$???` it only shows the last submitted number 110.
I want to show it like this:

......... lengte is 100

......... lengte is 110

Comment: please provide a result of print_r of your arrays, your question is not clear.

Comment: @AlirezaFallah Sorry next time i will

Comment: what is the relation between these two arrays? can you be more specific?

Comment: What is inside `$optellen` ?

Comment: @AlirezaFallah inside $optellen: Array
(
    [1] => 100
    [3] => 110
)

Comment: and you want both 100 and 110 be printed below each item of `$lijst['palen']` ?

Comment: @AlirezaFallah yes , $lijst['palen'] contains 'Array
(
    [63] => 2
    [123] => 2
)' And $optellen contains: Array ( [1] => 100 [3] => 110 ) I want the output to be 2=100 and the other 2=110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will handle it:

```
foreach ($lijst['palen'] as $valuepalen) {
    foreach ($optellen as $hoogtevalue) {
        echo $valuepalen."x Bekaclip palen (48mm / lengte ".$hoogtevalue".cm \n"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The second $valuepalen must be $hoogtevalue but then it prints only 100 and not 100 and 110

Comment: edited. this will print 4 lines for you, `2:100` `2:110` `2:100` `2:110`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to map the values from one array to the other, by the position that they sit in the array, rather than by their existing key.

You could use array_map with null as the first parameter to create a new array that consists of pairs from each.  (I've added a print_r of the mapped array below to demonstrate the data structure.)

You can then just loop through the pairs.

```
<?php
$one = [ 63 => 2, 123 => 2];
$two = [ 1 => 100, 3 => 110];

$pairs = array_map(null, $one, $two);
print_r($pairs);

foreach($pairs as $pair)
    printf("%d = %d\n", $pair[0], $pair[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 110
        )

)
2 = 100
2 = 110
```

Alternatively you could use the array_values function on both arrays to re-index them and then use keys for association.